# Simplifying VBA code - From column to 8*12 format

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and I want some advices regarding simplifying/making a code more dynamic so it is not specific to certain range.
I want to copy a data in the same column from different row to a 8 x 12 (x to y) format. My current codes are fully working but I am just wondering if there is a more dynamic way to do it as the ones I did took so much time just to find the relationship in the loop formula, and they are fixed to only 384 rows.
I am also aiming to exit sub when the row is empty to prevent an infinite loop. Below are the codes that I managed to craft:

```
Private Sub columnto96()

Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, a As Long, lr As Long
Dim src As Worksheet, dst As Worksheet

Set src = Sheet1 'setsheetsource
Set dst = Sheet3 'setsheetdest

lr = src.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

'for one plate
If lr <= 96 Then
    For y = 1 To 12
        For x = 1 To 8
            dst.Cells(x, y) = src.Cells(8 * y - 8 + x + 1, 4)
        Next x
    Next y
    Exit Sub
    
'for >1 plate
    ElseIf lr > 96 Then
        For y = 1 To 12
           For x = 1 To 8
             dst.Cells(x, y) = src.Cells(8 * y - 8 + x + 1, 4)
           Next x
        Next y
            
        'for more than 96 samples
         For x = 87 To 94
          For y = 1 To 12
           For z = 97 To 104
           dst.Cells(z - x, y) = src.Cells(z, 4)
        
            If z - x >= 17 Then Call nextcolumn Else
            Next z
            
            If src.Cells(lr + 1, 4) = "" Then Exit Sub
            
          Next y
         Next x
        
End If

End Sub

Private Sub nextcolumn()

Dim x As Long, z As Long, y As Long, lr As Long
Dim src As Worksheet, dst As Worksheet

Set src = Sheet1 'setsheetsource
Set dst = Sheet3 'setsheetdest
lr = src.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For y = 1 To 12
   For x = 1 To 8
   dst.Cells(x + 9, y) = src.Cells(8 * y + x + 89, 4)
   If src.Cells(8 * y + x + 89, 4) = "" Then Exit Sub
   Next x
Next y

If lr < 289 Or lr >= 193 Then
    For y = 1 To 12
       For x = 1 To 8
       dst.Cells(x + 18, y) = src.Cells(8 * y + x + 184, 4)
       If src.Cells(8 * y + x + 184, 4) = "" Then Exit Sub
       Next x
    Next y
    
    
ElseIf lr >= 289 Or lr < 385 Then
    For y = 1 To 12
        For x = 1 To 8
        dst.Cells(x + 27, y) = src.Cells(8 * y + x + 279, 4)
        If src.Cells(8 * y + x + 279, 4) = "" Then Exit Sub
        Next x
    Next y


Else: Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: If you put a thousand values in column `D` (starting with `D2`) of `Sheet1`, your code will generate 288 values in three 8x12 ranges with one empty row between them. Also, the third is incorrect since it starts with the last value of the second range thus actually writing 287 values. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What will be fixed and what should be variable (dynamic)? Maybe add some sample data and a few screenshots.

Comment: For example, you can make the following dynamic: the first cells of the source and the destination data, the number of empty rows between the sets, the number of rows (8), the number of columns (12), by columns (at this point) or by rows...etc. Add more detail to [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67467015/edit).

Comment: You might not even need loops either, it's possible to do some quicker flood-filling of formulae across ranges and then just convert them to hard values, depends if your code is running slow or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Column Sets (Column to Row by Column Format)

- The first two procedures do the same and both use the three accompanying functions.
- The 'star of the show' is the last function that does most of the heavy lifting.
- Adjust the values in the constants section and the worksheet references of the first procedure.
- If you opt for the second procedure, adjust the values where you find them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub getColumnSetsFlexible()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sFirst As String = "D2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    Const rCount As Long = 8
    Const cCount As Long = 12
    Const ByColumns As Boolean = True
    Const includeRemainder As Boolean = False
    Const EmptyRows As Long = 1
    
    ' Create worksheet references.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet1
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet3
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refColumn(sws.Range(sFirst))
    ' Validate Source Column Range.
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Column Range to Source Data Array.
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getColumn(rg)
    
    ' Write the column sets from Source Data Array to arrays of Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getColumnSets( _
        sData, rCount, cCount, ByColumns, includeRemainder)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Current Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    ' Declare Data Array Arrays Counter.
    Dim n As Long
    
    ' Loop through the arrays of Data Array.
    For n = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        ' Write the values of the current array of Data Array
        ' to the Current Destination Range.
        drg.Value = Data(n)
        ' Create a reference to the Next Destination Range.
        Set drg = drg.Offset(EmptyRows + rCount)
    Next n

End Sub

Sub getColumnSetsReadable()
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refColumn(Sheet1.Range("D2"))
    ' Validate Source Column Range.
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Column Range to Source Data Array.
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getColumn(rg)
    
    ' Write the column sets from Source Data Array to arrays of Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getColumnSets(sData, 8, 12, True, False)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Current Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Sheet3.Range("A2").Resize(8, 12)
    
    ' Declare Data Array Arrays Counter.
    Dim n As Long
    
    ' Loop through the arrays of Data Array.
    For n = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        ' Write the values of the current array of Data Array
        ' to the Current Destination Range.
        drg.Value = Data(n)
        ' Create a reference to the Next Destination Range.
        Set drg = drg.Offset(9)
    Next n

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a worksheet column, creates a reference to the range
'               from a given cell 'FirstCellRange' to the bottom-most
'               unoccupied cell i.e. all cells below the latter are empty
'               (="", ="'"... are not included).
'               If `NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty` is 'True', the bottom-most cell,
'               whose contents have a length of greater than 0, is condsidered
'               as the bottom-most unoccupied cell i.e. all cells below
'               the latter are blank ('Empty', ="", ="'"...).
' Remarks:      Although 'FirstCellRange' can be a range of any size,
'               only its first cell will be considered.
' Limitations:  If the worksheet contains filtered rows, both options may fail.
'               If it contains hidden rows, then only 'NonBlank' may fail.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function refColumn( _
    FirstCellRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "refColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
            Dim cLookIn As XlFindLookIn
            If NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty Then
                cLookIn = xlValues
            Else
                cLookIn = xlFormulas
            End If
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , cLookIn, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a column ('ColumnNumber')
'               of a range ('rg') to a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal doTranspose As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        If ColumnNumber > 0 And ColumnNumber <= rg.Columns.Count Then
            With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
                Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
                Dim Result As Variant
                If rCount > 1 Then
                    If doTranspose Then
                        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
                        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
                        Dim r As Long
                        For r = 1 To rCount
                            Result(1, r) = Data(r, 1)
                        Next r
                        getColumn = Result
                    Else
                        getColumn = .Value
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = .Value
                    getColumn = Result
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of a 2D one-based one-column array
'               to a jagged array (array of arrays) consisting of arrays
'               of a given number of rows and columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumnSets( _
    ByVal ColumnData As Variant, _
    ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
    ByVal ColumnsCount As Long, _
    Optional ByColumns As Boolean = False, _
    Optional includeRemainder As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(ColumnData, 1)
    Dim fCount As Long: fCount = Int(srCount / (RowsCount * ColumnsCount))
    Dim dRem As Long: dRem = srCount - fCount
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = fCount
    If includeRemainder Then
        If dRem > 0 Then
            dCount = dCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To dCount)
    Dim NewData As Variant: ReDim NewData(1 To RowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    
    If ByColumns Then
        If fCount > 0 Then
            For n = 1 To fCount
                Data(n) = NewData
                For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                    For r = 1 To RowsCount
                        i = i + 1
                        Data(n)(r, c) = ColumnData(i, 1)
                    Next r
                Next c
            Next n
        End If
        If includeRemainder Then
            If dRem > 0 Then
                Data(n) = NewData
                For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                    For r = 1 To RowsCount
                        i = i + 1
                        If i <= srCount Then
                            Data(n)(r, c) = ColumnData(i, 1)
                        End If
                    Next r
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If fCount > 0 Then
            For n = 1 To fCount
                Data(n) = NewData
                For r = 1 To RowsCount
                    For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                        i = i + 1
                        Data(n)(r, c) = ColumnData(i, 1)
                    Next c
                Next r
            Next n
        End If
        If includeRemainder Then
            If dRem > 0 Then
                Data(n) = NewData
                For r = 1 To RowsCount
                    For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                        i = i + 1
                        If i <= srCount Then
                            Data(n)(r, c) = ColumnData(i, 1)
                        End If
                    Next c
                Next r
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    getColumnSets = Data
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks you @vbasic2008, will let you know if it works! I made a mistake in my question, it should be 12*8 format. Replying to your question in the previous post, I am intending to copy data from a certain column to 12*8 format (I work in science industry where I use 96-wells-plate to load samples). I will screenshot it when I have access to my laptop.